# In '...as has often been the case',which content is the case?

Tags: grammar, as

From Roger Berry. (1993). Collins Cobuild English Guides: Articles. p. vii.

> Rules of usage are given which are not misleading, **as** has often been the case.

Does 'as' here lead a non-restrictive clause, meaning that misleading is the case?

And if change the order of 'as...' to

> As has often been the case, rules of usage are given which are not misleading.

do we get that 'rules of usage are given which are not misleading' is true(the case)?

Comment: It means, “It has often been the case with earlier works that their rules of usage are misleading. We, too, provide rules of usage, but ours are not misleading.” But the sentence you cite is poorly written. It is a good example of how misuse of the passive voice creates awkward results.